# Letter puzzle settings: scale, color and possition using cwpuzzle with beamer package

Tags: beamer, cwpuzzle

It is needed to configure Letter puzzle: scale (set zoom), color (change the default color black and white with other colors) and possition (move it slighty left) using cwpuzzle with beamer package. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage[unboxed]{cwpuzzle} %Para hacer pupiletras musicales
\usepackage{framed}% for shaded/shaded*
\colorlet{shadecolor}{white}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% set text colors for different objects
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=white}

%% set fonts
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Huge, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\ECFAugie}

%% Green Background Colour
%\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green!20!black}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green!11!black}

%% Random Dust Trails
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth, \the\paperheight); 
      \foreach \i in {1,...,30} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{random(0,10000)/5000-1}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{random(0,10000)/10000-0.1}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{random(0,10000)/1000-5}%
            \rotatebox{\r}{
                %\pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{\x\paperwidth}{\y\paperheight}, left, base]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LOGO_UNDAR_PNG_RGB.png}}
            }
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

%% use a small dash ('-') for a bulletpoint list
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{item}\small\ECFAugie{-}}

%% Frametitle
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{frametitle}
        \vskip17pt
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
        \insertframetitle \\
        \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%% remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%% Date in the Corner
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \rotatebox{30}{
        \ifx\insertdate\empty\else        
            \hspace*{0.25cm}\ECFAugie\insertshortdate\hspace*{0.5cm}
        \fi
    }
    \vspace*{-1cm}
}

% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{LOGO_UNDAR_PNG_RGB}}
}
\title{Taller de Musixtex}
\subtitle{Una introducción para Músicos}
\author{Aland Bravo Vecorena}
\date[02/02/23]{Huánuco, 02 de Febrero del 2023}
\institute{\LARGE Universidad Nacional Daniel Alomía Robles}

\begin{document}

% set handwritten font
\ECFAugie

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
    \frametitle{Pupiletras sobre \underline{Musixtex}}
    \centering
    %\begin{shaded}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    
    %\hspace*{-0.7cm}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
    \PuzzleUnitlength=13pt
    %\PuzzleDefineColorCell{R}{Crimson}
    %\PuzzleDefineColorCell{G}{Green!80}        
    \normalfont    
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \vspace*{-0.7cm}\begin{shaded}
    %\hspace*{-1.7cm}
    \begin{Puzzle}{16}{12}
        |*    |*    |[1]R  |A  |[2]S  |T     |E     |R     |I     |Z     |A    |D    |O    |[3]S |*  |*    |.
        |*    |*    |*     |*  |V     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |T    |*  |[4]T |.
        |*    |[5]L |*     |*  |G     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |Y    |*  |E    |.
        |[6]B |A    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |X    |.
        |E    |T    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
        |A    |E    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |[7]M |I    |K    |T    |E  |X    |.
        |M    |X    |*     |*  |*     |[8]V  |E     |C     |T     |O     |R    |I    |A    |L    |*  |*    |.
        |E    |M    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |[9]X  |E    |L    |A    |T    |E  |X    |.
        |R    |K    |*     |*  |[10]P |E     |R     |L     |*     |[11]L |A    |T    |E    |X    |*  |*    |.
        |*    |R    |[12]T |*  |[13]M |U     |S     |I     |X     |T     |E    |X    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
        |*    |C    |T     |*  |*     |[14]B |M     |P     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
        |*    |*    |F     |*  |[15]T |I     |K     |Z     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
    \end{Puzzle}
    \end{shaded}
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \ECFAugie
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \scriptsize
    \begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Horizontal}}
        \Clue{4}{RASTERIZADO}{Any mathematical process}
        \Clue{7}{MIKTEX}{The lowest value in a set of numbers through the highest value in the set}
        \Clue{8}{VECTORIAL}{A network of lines used for locating points}
        \Clue{9}{XELATEX}{Any symbol that could represent a number}
        \Clue{10}{PERL}{Graph that displays data using line segments}
        \Clue{11}{LATEX}{A model or drawing based on a ratio}
        \Clue{13}{MUSIXTEX}{Any mathematical process}
        \Clue{14}{BMP}{The lowest value in a set of numbers through the highest value in the set}
        \Clue{15}{TIKZ}{A network of lines used for locating points}
    \end{PuzzleClues}
        
    \begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Vertical}}
        \Clue{1}{STY}{the positions of a single digit in the whole number}
        \Clue{2}{TEX}{A graph that uses bars to display data}
        \Clue{3}{LATEXMKRC}{The use of rounding to determine a reasonable answer}
        \Clue{5}{SVG}{The number found most often}
        \Clue{6}{BEAMER}{The horizontal and vertical number lines used in a graph}
        \Clue{12}{TTF}{The horizontal and vertical number lines used in a graph}
    \end{PuzzleClues}
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    %\end{shaded}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
    \frametitle{Pupiletras sobre \underline{Musixtex}}
    \centering
    %\begin{shaded}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    
    %\hspace*{-0.7cm}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
    \PuzzleUnitlength=13pt
    %\PuzzleDefineColorCell{R}{Crimson}
    %\PuzzleDefineColorCell{G}{Green!80}        
    \normalfont    
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \vspace*{-0.7cm}\begin{shaded}
    %\hspace*{-1.7cm}
    \PuzzleSolution %Visualiza la solución
    \begin{Puzzle}{16}{12}
        |*    |*    |[1]R  |A  |[2]S  |T     |E     |R     |I     |Z     |A    |D    |O    |[3]S |*  |*    |.
        |*    |*    |*     |*  |V     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |T    |*  |[4]T |.
        |*    |[5]L |*     |*  |G     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |Y    |*  |E    |.
        |[6]B |A    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |X    |.
        |E    |T    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
        |A    |E    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |[7]M |I    |K    |T    |E  |X    |.
        |M    |X    |*     |*  |*     |[8]V  |E     |C     |T     |O     |R    |I    |A    |L    |*  |*    |.
        |E    |M    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |[9]X  |E    |L    |A    |T    |E  |X    |.
        |R    |K    |*     |*  |[10]P |E     |R     |L     |*     |[11]L |A    |T    |E    |X    |*  |*    |.
        |*    |R    |[12]T |*  |[13]M |U     |S     |I     |X     |T     |E    |X    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
        |*    |C    |T     |*  |*     |[14]B |M     |P     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
        |*    |*    |F     |*  |[15]T |I     |K     |Z     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
    \end{Puzzle}
    \end{shaded}
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \ECFAugie
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \scriptsize
    \begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Horizontal}}
        \Clue{4}{RASTERIZADO}{Any mathematical process}
        \Clue{7}{MIKTEX}{The lowest value in a set of numbers through the highest value in the set}
        \Clue{8}{VECTORIAL}{A network of lines used for locating points}
        \Clue{9}{XELATEX}{Any symbol that could represent a number}
        \Clue{10}{PERL}{Graph that displays data using line segments}
        \Clue{11}{LATEX}{A model or drawing based on a ratio}
        \Clue{13}{MUSIXTEX}{Any mathematical process}
        \Clue{14}{BMP}{The lowest value in a set of numbers through the highest value in the set}
        \Clue{15}{TIKZ}{A network of lines used for locating points}
    \end{PuzzleClues}
        
    \begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Vertical}}
        \Clue{1}{STY}{the positions of a single digit in the whole number}
        \Clue{2}{TEX}{A graph that uses bars to display data}
        \Clue{3}{LATEXMKRC}{The use of rounding to determine a reasonable answer}
        \Clue{5}{SVG}{The number found most often}
        \Clue{6}{BEAMER}{The horizontal and vertical number lines used in a graph}
        \Clue{12}{TTF}{The horizontal and vertical number lines used in a graph}
    \end{PuzzleClues}
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    %\end{shaded}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you are not going to use the random dust trails, you should remove the `\setbeamertemplate{background}{...}`. The loop is rather slow and you aren't using it for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - scale (set zoom)

As already shown in my last answer, the size can be controlled with `\PuzzleUnitlength=...`

> - color (change the default color black and white with other colors)

The puzzle itself does not use colours. The lines and the text will be printed in the colour of the surrounding text and the cells itself are transparent, so they will show whatever background is behind them

> - position (move it slighty left)

you can use the `nocenter` package option. Once the automatic centering is switched off, the puzzle is left aligned.

---

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    
\usepackage[unboxed,nocenter]{cwpuzzle} %Para hacer pupiletras musicales
\usepackage{framed}% for shaded/shaded*

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

% set text colors for different objects
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=white}

%% set fonts
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Huge, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\ECFAugie}

%% Green Background Colour
%\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green!20!black}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green!11!black}

%% use a small dash ('-') for a bulletpoint list
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{item}\small\ECFAugie{-}}

%% Frametitle
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{frametitle}
        \vskip17pt
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
        \insertframetitle \\
        \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%% remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%% Date in the Corner
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \rotatebox{30}{
        \ifx\insertdate\empty\else        
            \hspace*{0.25cm}\ECFAugie\insertshortdate\hspace*{0.5cm}
        \fi
    }
    \vspace*{-1cm}
}

% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{LOGO_UNDAR_PNG_RGB}}
}
\title{Taller de Musixtex}
\subtitle{Una introducción para Músicos}
\author{Aland Bravo Vecorena}
\date[02/02/23]{Huánuco, 02 de Febrero del 2023}
\institute{\LARGE Universidad Nacional Daniel Alomía Robles}

\begin{document}

% set handwritten font
\ECFAugie

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
  \frametitle{Pupiletras sobre \underline{Musixtex}}
  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \PuzzleUnitlength=10pt
    \normalfont    
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=red}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \only<2->{\PuzzleSolution}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{green}
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{shaded}
    \begin{Puzzle}{16}{12}
        |*    |*    |[1]R  |A  |[2]S  |T     |E     |R     |I     |Z     |A    |D    |O    |[3]S |*  |*    |.
        |*    |*    |*     |*  |V     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |T    |*  |[4]T |.
        |*    |[5]L |*     |*  |G     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |Y    |*  |E    |.
        |[6]B |A    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |X    |.
        |E    |T    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
        |A    |E    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |[7]M |I    |K    |T    |E  |X    |.
        |M    |X    |*     |*  |*     |[8]V  |E     |C     |T     |O     |R    |I    |A    |L    |*  |*    |.
        |E    |M    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |[9]X  |E    |L    |A    |T    |E  |X    |.
        |R    |K    |*     |*  |[10]P |E     |R     |L     |*     |[11]L |A    |T    |E    |X    |*  |*    |.
        |*    |R    |[12]T |*  |[13]M |U     |S     |I     |X     |T     |E    |X    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
        |*    |C    |T     |*  |*     |[14]B |M     |P     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
        |*    |*    |F     |*  |[15]T |I     |K     |Z     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
    \end{Puzzle}
    \end{shaded}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Horizontal}}
        \Clue{4}{RASTERIZADO}{Any mathematical process}
        \Clue{7}{MIKTEX}{The lowest value in a set of numbers through the highest value in the set}
        \Clue{8}{VECTORIAL}{A network of lines used for locating points}
        \Clue{9}{XELATEX}{Any symbol that could represent a number}
        \Clue{10}{PERL}{Graph that displays data using line segments}
        \Clue{11}{LATEX}{A model or drawing based on a ratio}
        \Clue{13}{MUSIXTEX}{Any mathematical process}
        \Clue{14}{BMP}{The lowest value in a set of numbers through the highest value in the set}
        \Clue{15}{TIKZ}{A network of lines used for locating points}
    \end{PuzzleClues}
        
    \begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Vertical}}
        \Clue{1}{STY}{the positions of a single digit in the whole number}
        \Clue{2}{TEX}{A graph that uses bars to display data}
        \Clue{3}{LATEXMKRC}{The use of rounding to determine a reasonable answer}
        \Clue{5}{SVG}{The number found most often}
        \Clue{6}{BEAMER}{The horizontal and vertical number lines used in a graph}
        \Clue{12}{TTF}{The horizontal and vertical number lines used in a graph}
    \end{PuzzleClues}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]